# Can I connect to iTunes music shares using Amarok?

Tags: music, itunes, mediaserver, amarok, daap

The [Amarok manual](http://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Organization/Collection/RemoteCollections/DAAP) claims:

> Amarok automatically shows the tracks from the server in the Media Sources -> Local Music pane and no further configuration is required.

But Amarok did not automatically work with no configuration:

[image: Amarok]

What am I doing wrong?

I've confirmed that sharing is enabled in iTunes,

[image: iTunes]

and that the share is visible in Rhythmbox,

[image: Rhythmbox]

so I believe the problem is within Amarok.

How can I make Amarok connect to the share?

Comment: did you try going to "media devices" in properties and add a new device, choosing "share" for device type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is sadly no. This will work between iTunes only.

In your link it mentions that the protocol "...was first used for the iTunes music player" but did not mention current support for accessing iTunes Shared music.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol

> Beginning with iTunes 4.2, Apple introduced authentication to DAAP
>   sharing, meaning that the only clients that could connect to iTunes
>   servers were other instances of iTunes. This was further modified in
>   iTunes 4.5 to use a custom hashing algorithm, rather than the standard
>   MD5 function used previously. Both authentication methods were
>   successfully reverse engineered within months of release.[5]
>
> With iTunes 7.0, a new 'Client-DAAP-Validation' header hash is needed
>   when connecting to an iTunes 7.0 server. This does not affect
>   third-party DAAP servers, but all current DAAP clients (including
>   official iTunes before iTunes 7.0) will fail to connect to an iTunes
>   7.0 server, receiving a '403 Forbidden' HTTP error. The iTunes 7.0 authentication traffic analysis seem to indicate that a certificate
>   exchange is performed to calculate the hash sent in the
>   'Client-DAAP-Validation' header.
>
> As of July 15, 2014, the iTunes 7.0+ DAAP authentication still hasn't
>   been reverse engineered, so no third-party application can stream from
>   servers running iTunes software (from 7.x, all the way up to and
>   including version 11.x)

---

However; there are workarounds. (Which means not using iTunes)

You can use a diffrent Music Server that uses DAAP to send your music.

Then direct it to your iTunes music folder, from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1391 the location of iTunes music (This worked on my mac, however I collected my music through iTunes through CD and not from iTunes store - not sure if it changes anything)

> ```
> Mac OS X: /Users/username/Music/iTunes/
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\
> Windows Vista: C:\Users\username\Music\iTunes\
> Windows 7: C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\
> Windows 8: C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\
> ```

I tested out firefly for mac (looks like a dead project), but there are other music servers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol listed under **DAAP servers**

Comment: Although disappointing, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: It's a shame that both Amarok and Rhythmbox do nothing to curb the illusion that we can expect this to work with iTunes. Rhythmbox is even actively misleading—"Retrieving songs from music share"—and apparently has been [since 2006](https://launchpad.net/rhythmbox/+bug/62842)!